# My RelativeLayout doesn't fill the screen! (screen shot included)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this activity:

[image]

User enters a value, presses the button and the result is displayed at the bottom (after some calculation is done). As you can see I have a layout at the bottom in green, this is where the answer is displayed in white text. But this section isn't filling the entire width of the screen it has those white edges on the sides and at the bottom. So just to be clear, I want it to fill the edges and the bottom.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="***"
    tools:showIn="@layout/***">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Present value"
        android:id="@+id/present_value_text_box"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/eq"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="282dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/investment_value_answer_text_box"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="60dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout >


</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong? I set the width of the layout to "fill_parent" I assumed that would do it but maybe I'm wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have some "padding" in the root element, that's why there are margins around the green area. Keep "padding_top" if you like, get rid of the rest.

Comment: check where you are going wrong before posting...

Comment: Remove padding properties from your main(Root) RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> REMOVE FROM ROOT VIEW (Relative Layout) in XML :

```
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following lines from the ROOT RelativeLayout:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

You are also setting a custom `layout_width` for your TextView, which is not a good practice. Please read the following docs:

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

[Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: thanks I fixed that too! That was actually me trying to make it fill the screen before hand.